# Using data from one table in another mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, database, copy, one-to-one

I'm having trouble using a variable stored in a session in another table as an ID.

I have a table called userbase and one called userpage:

```
**userbase**
id          int(15)
username    Varchar(15)
password    Varchar(15)
email       Varchar(40)

**userpage**
id          int(15)
name        Varchar(30)
info        Varchar(300)
userID      Varchar(15)
```

when a user logs on at the index page they are sent to a different page with username stored in the url like so

```
"location: myPage.php?message=$message?UserName=$UserName"
```

On that page I want to use assign userID to the value of username. I've tried the following

```
session_start();
include "common.php";
$message = $_GET['message'];
$UserName = $_SESSION['UserName'];
....
$agentID = $_SESSION['userID'];
....
$Query = "INSERT INTO $Test_Table VALUES ('0',
  '".mysql_escape_string($formValue["name"])."',
    '".mysql_escape_string($formValue["info"])."',
      '".mysql_escape_string($UserName)."')
```

but that just leaves the userID field empty. Where have I went wrong?

EDIT: I've tried replaceing $_SESSION['UserName'] with $GET['UserName'] but still no luck I think the problem must be assigning the value to $_SESSION['userID'] as this is the only mention of it I make in the code, but I don't know what I'm meant to do

Comment: Have you set `$_SESSION['UserName']` on a previous page?

Comment: Make sure you use session_start() on every file that is supposed to use sessions

Comment: Also, make sure you have capitals in the right spots etc. $userName is not the same as $UserName for example (can happen sometimes when using capitals in variables, I know I made that mistake a couple of times :P)

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the username via GET and in the code your accessing it via SESSION which will not work.

Right way is :

```
$UserName = $_GET['UserName'];
```

Also please show the code where are you assigning value to `$_SESSION['userID']`

Comment: I've tried replaceing $_SESSION with $_GET but still no luck

I think the problem must be assigning the value to $_SESSION['userID'] as this is the only mention of it I make in the code, but I don't know what I'm meant to do after this.

Answer (score 0):

UserName may not have been initialized in the index page ..looks like u are trying to pass an uninitialized value to the other page .